# import slider values from a html form to flask application

Tags: html, flask

I have a HTML with sliders and I'm trying to get the values of the sliders to my flask application:

HTML

```
<form method="POST">
<div class="slidecontainer" id="slide_container_f">
<p>Faturamento:<span id="demo"></span></p>
<input type="range" min={{min}} max={{max}} value={{max}} class="slider" id="myRange" name="faturamento">
</div>
</form>
```

Flask application

```
@app.route('/modelos',methods=['GET','POST'])
def modelos():
#to listen from slider
    faturamento=''
    if request.method == 'POST':
        faturamento=request.form['faturamento']
    return render_template("modelos.html",min=0,max=100)
```

However, faturamento is never updated with the value of slider. Could you provide me a hint about why I'm not been able to retrieve the values?

Answer (score 4):

You are missing a submit button in your form to submit the form to the server. How are you submitting the form to the server?

HTML should look like

```
<form method="POST" action="{{url_for('modelos')}}">
    <div class="slidecontainer" id="slide_container_f">
    <p>Faturamento:<span id="demo"></span></p>
    <input type="range" min={{min}} max={{max}} value={{max}} class="slider" 
        id="myRange" name="faturamento">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </div>
</form>
```

When you hit submit, what is the value that `faturamento` variable is getting in your flask route? Can you print it and see what the value is? is it None? is it an empty string?

**UPDATE**

If you don't want to have a submit button then you should use an AJAX call to communicate with the server whenever the slider changes

JS Code

```
$(function(){
    var form = $('form');
    $('#myRange').on('change mouseup', function(){
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: form.action,
            data: form.serialize(),
        }).done(function(res){
            //do something with the response from the server
        });
    });
});
```

Whenever the slider will change when you release the mouse, it will fire an AJAX call to your `modelos` route and the value of `faturamento` should be the current value of the slider.

Comment: If I didn't want a submit buttom I would need to do a jquery. Do you have any suggestions?